# How to install matplotlib on Raspberry Pi 4 B?

Tags: python, matplotlib, ubuntu, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4

I'm wondering if anyone might know why I'm unable to install matplotlib version 3.3.4 on my RPi 4B. I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS with Python 3.6.13. Here is what I tried:

```
pip install matplotlib==3.3.4
```

However, I get a bunch of red text with an error telling me it failed to build the wheel. Here is the error output:

```
  /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/_backend_agg.cpython-36m-aarch64-linux-gnu.so.BXBFax.ltrans0.ltrans.o: relocation R_AARCH64_ADR_PREL_PG_HI21 against symbol `__stack_chk_guard@@GLIBC_2.17' which may bind externally can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
  /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/_backend_agg.cpython-36m-aarch64-linux-gnu.so.BXBFax.ltrans0.ltrans.o(.text+0x3fc): unresolvable R_AARCH64_ADR_PREL_PG_HI21 relocation against symbol `__stack_chk_guard@@GLIBC_2.17'
  /usr/bin/ld: final link failed: bad value
  collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
  error: command 'aarch64-linux-gnu-g++' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for matplotlib
  Running setup.py clean for matplotlib
Failed to build matplotlib
Installing collected packages: matplotlib
    Running setup.py install for matplotlib ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-yhqnk_yg/matplotlib/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-yhqnk_yg/matplotlib/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-d9f_68ud/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /usr/local/include/python3.6/matplotlib
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-yhqnk_yg/matplotlib/
```

It seems like there is an issue with the compilation of one of the dependencies but I'm not sure how to resolve this problem, or if it's just an issue with my specific OS. I've done an exhaustive search of the internet for a solution but it seems no one has had the same problem as me.